# Need help with testing class for redirectling page

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, pagereference

I'm unable to cover the last 3 lines of the apex class. 
Following is my Apex class..

```
public with sharing class redirect{

public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public List<orders__c> orderId {get;set;}

public redirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
    Public Pagereference go(){

        currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('orderid');
        //currentRecordId  = order number from SAP
        system.debug('---currentRecordId  ---'+currentRecordId  );

        List<orders__c> orderId = new List <orders__c>();

        orderId = [select id from orders__c where Orders__c =: currentRecordId];

        if(orderId.size()==0)
        {
             ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Order ID not available!'));
             return null;

        }

       else
       {
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/TrackingClass?id='+orderId[0].id);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;
        }

  }

 }
```

Test class ...

```
@isTest
public class redirect_TEST
{  
          static testMethod void Test(){

          Account acc = new Account(Name='ABC Corp.');
          insert acc;

          orders__c tempOrder = new orders__c(name = '0001234567', account__c = acc.id );
          insert tempOrder;

          Test.startTest();

          PageReference pageRef = Page.redirect;
          Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

          ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(tempOrder);
          ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('orderid',tempOrder.name);
          pageRef.setRedirect(true);

          redirect ec = new redirect(sc);

          System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('orderId', 'tempOrder.id');

          ec.go();                        
          Test.stopTest();

        }              

    }
          static testMethod void Test1(){

          Account acc1 = new Account(Name='1ABC Corp.');
          insert acc1;

          orders__c tempOrder1 = new orders__c(name = '00011234567', account__c = acc1.id );

          Test.startTest();

          PageReference pageRef1 = Page.redirect;
          Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef1);

          ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc1 = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(tempOrder1);
          ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('orderid',tempOrder1.name);
          pageRef1.setRedirect(true);
          redirectec1 = new redirect(sc1);
          ec1.go();                        
          Test.stopTest();


     }
 }
```

Comment: Make another test method where you don't assign any value to the orderId like you do in the others tests using this line: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('orderid',tempOrder1.name);. Also you should assert the outcomes of your tests. That means you don't have to create a record for the order__c object

Comment: I tried putting...ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('orderid',''); to the second method. No luck!

Comment: Share your code. You will have a problem with how the class is implemented. You are checking if the list has any items and if it doesn't you are selecting the first item from the list which will give you an error: accessing a null value. I recommend reviewing your code.

Comment: My  code is already shared above. I am currently trying to review my code.

Comment: I meant to edit your answer with the test method you've just created.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe Thanks for your help. I had few mistakes in testing class. It's covering all of them. I guess I messed up :)

Comment: Hi @MihaiNeagoe. Could you add the first comment as your answer. Im gonna accet it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another test method where you don't assign any value to the `orderId` like you do in the others tests using this line: `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('orderid',tempOrder1.name);`.

Also you should assert the outcomes of your tests. That means you don't have to create a record for the `Order__c` object